# Perform multi keyboard operation with click on a single object in test complete

Tags: c#, keyboard, keyboard-events, testcomplete

I have a test complete window object for ex Obj1. on the same object i need to perform action CTRL + Shift + Alt + double click at the same time . How to perform this multi select and click operation in test complete

Answer (score 0):

As long as the doubleclick is available for the object in question, You should be able to record this type of action using the record and replay.  You should reach out to your sales rep, or open a support case if you are having trouble doing this.